# Java "&" vs "|" while statement issue

Tags: java

I'm new to Java as of the past day or two and I've been messing around making some very basic programs. I have the following code as a simple number guessing program

```
public class GUESS2 {
public static void main(String args[])
        throws java.io.IOException {

        //This program will have you solve a numeric puzzle using different hints as you get closer

        int answer='5', guess=0, i=0;

        char ignore;

        do{

            i++;
            System.out.print("Can you guess the number I'm thinking of???");
            guess = (int) System.in.read();

            if(guess==answer) System.out.println("CORRECT!!!"); 

            if(guess >answer) System.out.println("Too high!");

            if(guess <answer) System.out.println("Too low!");

            do{
                ignore=(char) System.in.read();
            }while (ignore != '\n');

            } while(answer!=guess && i != 5);


        } 

    }
```

My issue here is with the "while" statment. I want it to exit this loop when EITHER answer=guess or i=5. When I use | or || it gives me the opposite and ONLY exits when I do answer=guess and i=5 at the same time which seems backwards to me.This current code using "&&" works when EITHER answer=guess or i=5 which doesn't make sense to me.

Again I'm a beginner and I appreciate you guys taking the time to help me- probably something simple but I've messed with it for a while.

Comment: Remember -- the condition is for *continuing* the loop. So you want a condition that would be *invalidated* when `answer == guess || i == 5` -- in other words, the opposite of that condition.

Comment: The code is correct, your expectation is wrong. [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Law) might help.

Comment: That article definitely helped to clarify things for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the possibilities. First, with OR(||) operator:

```
(answer != guess || i != 5)
```

If answer is equal to the guess, answer != guess evaluates to false, which, based in what you described, should make the program exit. However, i != 5 will still be true, so the whole statement will evaluate to true, making the program keep going, while the statement is true.

If answer is equal to the guess, and i == 5, both will evaluate to false, and, as none of them are true, the OR will evaluate to false, making the loop exit.

Now, with AND(&&) operator:

```
(answer != guess && i != 5)
```

If answer is equal to the guess, answer != guess evaluates to false, and, as it is an AND operator, which requires both to be true, the statement will evaluate to false, making the loop exit. If i is equal to 5, i != 5 evaluates to false, and, as already said, will make the statement evaluate to false, and the loop exit.

Hope to have helped.

EDIT: A [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/common.html) I found, may help you, see the 8th item.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the loop when either A or B is true, then you want to stay as long as this isn't the case: when both A and B are false.  Which is just how your code reads.

Comment: A-ha!!! Now that makes sense to me. When you put it more in terms of "False + false" vs. "False + True" & "True vs. False". I also think I was considering it more of an exit statement as opposed to a continue statement. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

The && gives you the behaviour you want because it requires both of those conditions to evaluate to true in order to continue. This means that if answer equals guess (the first conditions fails), or i equals five (the second condition fails), the loop will exit. However, with the || operator, you're saying continue on as long as either one of these is true. They're known as logical and and logical or, respectively. This should help:

a && b -> if both are true, evaluates to true, otherwise false

a || b -> if either are true, evaluates to true, otherwise false

Answer (score 0):

it does not make sense because you did not read the things in a right way:

What you are asking for is: keep on looping ***until either*** answer == guess ***OR*** i ==5

However, this piece of code actually means:

```
do{
} while(answer!=guess && i != 5);
```

"keep on looping ***if both*** answer is not guess ***and*** i != 5"

which essentially mean the same thing.  The reason you find it counter-intuitive is because you are thinking of the "stopping condition" while do-while loop is specifying the "continuation condition"

Some languages (not Java) do provide do-until loop, which is doing what you want.  It may look like this if it is provided in Java:

```
do {
} until (answer == guess || i == 5)
```